# How to turn on keyboard backlit using the touchpad?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, keyboard, windows-registry, touchpad

I have an HP Pavilion 15" CS2082TX laptop running windows 10.

Whenever the keyboard backlit goes off after staying inactive for some time, I have to hit a key to turn it on again. How can I turn on the backlit again by just tapping on the touchpad instead?

I've used an old driver for the same and it worked but that was not a precision driver.
Searched for some registry changes but couldn't find any.

Help me out, please.

Thank You.

Comment: Which model of HP laptop?

Comment: @spikey_richie hp pavilion15-cs2082tx

Comment: can someone help?